# custom groupby function pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, group-by

I have a following dataframe:

[image]

I would like to group by id and add a flag column which contains Y if anytime Y has occurred against id, resultant DF would like following:

[image]

Here is my approach which is too time consuming and not sure of correctness:

```py
temp=pd.DataFrame()
j='flag'
for i in df['id'].unique():
  test=df[df['id']==i]
  test[j]=np.where(np.any((test[j]=='Y')),'Y',test[j])
temp=temp.append(test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare `flag` to `Y`, group by `id`, and use `any`:

```py
new_df = (df['flag'] == 'Y').groupby(df['id']).any().map({True:'Y', False:'N'}).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
   id flag
0   1    Y
1   2    Y
2   3    N
3   4    N
4   5    Y
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do `groupby + max` since `Y > N`:

```
df.groupby('id', as_index=False)['flag'].max()
```

---

```
   id flag
0   1    Y
1   2    Y
2   3    N
3   4    N
4   5    Y
```